# Center text between two divs

Tags: html, css, jsx

I'm trying to center a text between two floating divs. The problem is, that the text does not center properly, even though I followed every step I could find online.
Here's the code I used to try to accomplish my goal:

```css
.EditingApp-head {
  background-color: #222;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.EditingApp-head-logo {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 10%;
}

.EditingApp-head-logo-image {
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}

.EditingApp-head-logo-text {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.EditingApp-head-title {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.EditingApp-head-end {
  float: right;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div className="EditingApp">
  <div className="EditingApp-head">
    <div className="EditingApp-head-logo">
      <img src={logo} className="EditingApp-head-logo-image" alt="logo" />
      <p className="EditingApp-head-logo-text">SyncPad</p>
    </div>
    <div className="EditingApp-head-end" />
    <p className="EditingApp-head-title">Title</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p style={{textAlign: "center"}}>center</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The text 'Title' centers slightly to the right, so it somehow ignores the right div.
Does anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Put `<center></center>` around your paragraph and if i understand well it will help.

Comment: `center` is deprecated in html5, so you shouldn't use it. And principally you need to separate markup (html) from design (css). Centering something is visual/design, and doesn't belong in the markup. Try offering another solution.

Comment: Do you need to center just text in div or to center div between divs? I didn't understand.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes i know that i study it. :D I'm just giving quick and short answer. ;D

Comment: @labris I need to center 'title' in the middle of the head-div

Comment: This is reaaaaalllly outdated advice.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the floated content. The `inline` content in your `p` is going to wrap around the floated content, which will offset it depending on the width of the floated content. To center the title `p`, apply `margin: 0 10%` so that the inline content in the `p` isn't affected by the surrounding floated content.

```css
.EditingApp-head {
  background-color: #222;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.EditingApp-head-logo {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 10%;
}

.EditingApp-head-logo-image {
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}

.EditingApp-head-logo-text {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.EditingApp-head-title {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="EditingApp">
  <div class="EditingApp-head">
    <div class="EditingApp-head-logo">
      <img src={logo} class="EditingApp-head-logo-image" alt="logo" />
      <p class="EditingApp-head-logo-text">SyncPad</p>
    </div>
    <p class="EditingApp-head-title">Title</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the `className` comes from the fact that this is taken from a JSX file, thus it is correct like it was

Comment: @Chester I'm sure it was, but I can't replicate that here. I'm assuming you have some kind of error in your syntax. It all works as regular CSS, which I'm assuming is what the JSX compiles to. However, if you aren't looking for a CSS answer, you should revert your post code to JSX and use a JSX tag on your post.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep that in mind.
The 'title' element is meant to be in the middle, the 'center' paragraph was  just for reference

Comment: I'm sorry, I think it wasn't clear enough in the original question. I updated it, so that everybody gets that 'Title' was the original target

Comment: @Chester is the syntax for `<div className="EditingApp-head-end" />` correct? In HTML a div isn't self-closing, but I don't know about your template language.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. After some playing around, somehow, it just started to align properly. I'll post an answer shortly

Comment: @Chester it's because the floated elements take up space and offset the text. Use `margin: 0 10%` on the title paragraph and the text will be in the center.

Comment: This is a painfully simple solution to my problem! The whole point of the `end` div was to fill up 10%

Comment: @Chester in that case, I would float the `p` left, and give it `width: 80%`, and remove the right element. updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around, I got it to work. Thanks to all who tried to help me. Here's the final CSS:

```
.EditingApp-head {
    background-color: #222;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.EditingApp-head-logo {
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 10%;
}

.EditingApp-head-logo-image {
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    float: left;
}

.EditingApp-head-logo-text {
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: white;
}

.EditingApp-head-title {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.EditingApp-head-end {
    float: right;
    width: 10%;
}
```